# Need to Find the COM DLL from an interop dll

Tags: c#, com, interop

I have a Interop dll in a c# project, But I am not able to findout the corresponding COM dll associated with it. Please let me know, how to find out the actual COM dll from its interop dll.

Answer (score 1):

Got it.
One way is to use any one of its class in the project. Then go to definition of it, which will take us to Metadata. we can note down the GUID and then search it in registry, if that is available, like this one.

```
namespace NETWORKLIST
{
[ClassInterface(0)]
[Guid("DCB00C01-570F-4A9B-8D69-199FDBA5723B")]
[ComSourceInterfaces("NETWORKLIST.INetworkEvents")]
```